# Iterator in aggregate (linq)?

Tags: c#, linq, iterator, aggregate

Lets say I have a small integer array like this:

```
{10,20,30}
```

Now for the items of that array I want to apply the following formula:

```
10^(arrayLenght-1) + 20^{arrayLenght-2) + 30^{arrayLenght-3}
```

Is there a way to accompish this by using the linq aggregate methode though you need some kind of an iterator, which aggregate doesnt implement when I see this right?

Comment: Where are the elements in the array supposed to be used in the formula?  It would help if you showed how to do what you want with a for-loop

Comment: In C#, `^` is XOR, this will affect your return value

Comment: ^ is supposed to be a power operator here. sry for the confusion

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
array.Select((num, index) => Math.Pow(num, items.Length - index - 1)).Sum();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var a = new int[]{10, 20, 30};
int i = 0;
a.Sum(x => Math.Pow(x, a.Length - ++i));
```

It uses `Sum` method because it's more accurate here.

also you can use:

```
var a = new int[]{10, 20, 30};
a.Select((x,i)=> Math.Pow(x,a.Length-(i+1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try summing the results of a select instead of using aggregate

```
result = values.Select((t, index) => Math.Pow(t, (values.Length - (index + 1)))).Sum();
```

Comment: index starts with `0`.

Comment: @Sayse Yes. Which is what was asked for in the original posting.

Comment: @Corak. Yep. may bad. Editing

Answer (score 0):

The given answers are best to solve this problem, however if you need an aggregate function that exposes the iteration index, you can write your own.

```cs
public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, int, TAccumulate> func)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    if (func == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(func));

    var accumulate = seed;
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        accumulate = func(accumulate, item, i);
        i++;
    }
    return accumulate;
}
```